# BitmapFrame.Create fails with escaped characters in Uri

Tags: c#, wpf, uri

I am using WPF/C# in VS2017.
My code takes a path to an image file as a string and tries to load it into a BitmapFrame, which has worked fine mostly, except someone tested it with some image files from a Mac and it threw an exception. It turns out that the filename contains the character #F025, which in Windows is just displayed as a thick dot.

The files are photos, named from the photograph title. This one had a question mark in it, but ended up with #F025.

Anyway, the code converts the string to a Uri and then uses BitmapFrame as follows:

```
    public new void Init()
    {
        Source = new Uri(Path);
        fi = new FileInfo(Path);
        BitmapImage bs;
        try
        {
            Image = BitmapFrame.Create(Source);
            Metadata = new ExifMetadata(Image);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Error = e.Message;
            IsBroken = true;
        }
```

When I look at the Uri "Source" in the debugger, then #F025 character has been replaced with "%25EF%2580%25A5". The Create function throws a "File Not Found" exception.

If there any way of converting this to a Uri that the Create function will accept, or perhaps just using the string Path to load it instead? I did try using a stream with the filename but that didn't work either.

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to create the BitmapFrame from a FileStream. Note that `BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad` must be set in order to be able to close the stream immediately after the Create call.

```
using (var stream = File.OpenRead(Path))
{
    Image = BitmapFrame.Create(stream, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
}
```

Comment: Many thanks, that worked a treat. I had to change it in a few other places, but it's all working great now.